# Which closed $n$-manifolds are continuous images of spheres?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

A closed $n$-manifold is taken to mean a compact *topological* $n$-manifold without boundary.

I have been thinking about (higher) homotopy groups and possible analogues, and while I have good intuition for closed curves being continuous images of the circle*, my intuition rapidly decreases with increasing dimension. Still, I would like to keep the question as intuitive as possible, which is why I narrowed it down to (topological) manifolds.

> **Question 1:** Are there closed $n$-manifolds $M^n$, $ n \geq 3$, that are not continuous images of $\mathbb{S}^n$? If so, can we nevertheless find $m > n$ such that $M^n$ is a continuous image of $\mathbb{S}^m$? (In other words, are there closed $n$-manifolds that are not continuous images of any spheres?)

For example, IIRC there are many surjective maps $\mathbb{S}^2 \to \Sigma_g$, where $\Sigma_g$ is an orientable closed surface of genus $g$ (needs a reference). Also, for non-orientable closed surfaces, I guess we can start with the covering $S^2 \to \mathbb{RP}^2$.

> **Question 2:** Is there a classification (up to homotopy equivalence) of closed $n$-manifolds, $n \geq 3$, that are continuous images of $\mathbb{S}^n$? If not, is there a reason why such a classification could be deemed hopeless? Can we improve on that by assuming smoothness throughout?

*Well, strictly speaking, closed curves are continuous maps from the circle and their images are called traces of the closed curves, but I hope you will forgive me the abuse of terminology.

Comment: It seems there is a surjective map $[-1,1] \to M$ (space filling) then there are surjection from $\mathbb S^n$ by composition.

Comment: A perhaps more interesting question is whether for a given $n$-manifold $M$ there is a map from $S^n$ with non-zero degree. Then a surface of genus $g>0$ would be an example where this is not the case. In fact this is a part of a more general theory, A manifold $M_{1}$ is said to dominate $M_{2}$ is there is a map $F:M_{1} \rightarrow M_{2}$ with non-zero degree. This gives a partial order on the set of manifolds and is related to many topics in geoemetry and topology.

Comment: @ArcticChar: Thanks! I hadn't considered the possibility of space-filling curves. That certainly trivializes the question in the continuous category.

Comment: @NickL: I guess, that would have been the more interesting question, but I was not interested in that. I actually wanted to know what kind of "shapes" $n$-spheroids can take, i.e. what shapes (can) arise from (higher) homotopy groups. That's all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each connected compact $n$-manifold (with our without boundary) is the continuous image of $S^m$ for all $m \ge 1$. To see this, note that $\phi : S^m \to I = [0,1], \phi(x_1,\ldots,x_{m+1}) = \lvert x_1 \rvert$, is a continuous surjection.

$M$ can be covered by finitely many closed $B_1,\ldots, B_k \subset M$ which are homeomophic to the cube $I^n$. It is well-known that there exists a continuous surjection $f_2 : I \to I^2$. By iteration we get continuous surjections $f_n : I \to I^n$ and thus continuous surjections $f^i_n : I \to B_i$. Hence there exist continuous surjections $g_i : J_i = [\frac{2i-2}{2k},\frac{2i-1}{2k} ] \to B_i$. Choose paths $u_i : L_i = [\frac{2i-1}{2k},\frac{2i}{2k} ] \to M$ such that $u_i(\frac{2i-1}{2k}) = b_i = g_i(\frac{2i-1}{2k})$ and $u_i(\frac{2i}{2k}) = a_{i+1} = g_{i+1}(\frac{2i}{2k})$, $i = 1,\ldots, k$, where we set formally $a_{k+1} = b_k$.

Define
$$\psi : I \to M, \psi(t)  = \begin{cases} g_i(t) & t \in J_i \\u_i(t) & t \in L_i \\  \end{cases} $$

This is a continuous surjection, hence also $\psi \circ \phi$ is one.

Comment: More generally, every connected, locally path-connected compact metrizable space (a Peano continuum) is the continuous image of $[0,1]$ (Hahn-Mazurkiewicz Theorem). But this is a harder result.

Comment: @Paul Frost: Thanks! That certainly settles the question. Frankly, I was hoping for a more exciting outcome, but on the other hand it's good to know that one can realize all kinds of shapes by means of space-filling curves.

Answer (score 5):

You can also argue like so I believe: endow $M$ with a riemannian metric $g$ and pick a point $m\in M$. Unless I'm mistaken the restriction of the exponential map $\exp_{m}$ to the closed ball $B$ centered at $0$ of radius $\mathrm{diam}_g(M)$ is a smooth surjection $B\to M$. You thus get an onto map $S^n\to T_mM\to M$ where the first map is the projection $S^n\to B\subset T_mM$ parallel to the $(n+1)$-th coordinate (+ scaling by $\mathrm{diam}_g(M)$).

Comment: Maybe you want a complete Riemannian metric.

Comment: On a compact manifold, every Riemannian metric is complete.

Comment: OP is considering topological manifolds, so you cannot always put a Riemannian metric on their manifold.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: it's cool, it's nice to have a different take. Olivier Bégassat is addressing in a broad sense the last part of my question 2, where I restrict attention to the smooth setting (though initially only under the assumption that not all closed manifolds can be realized as images of spheres). It's good to know an argument in the smooth category.